# how to track certain files in subdirectories but not all the other files with git?

Tags: git, gitignore

I'd like to track files in this style

```
# Ignore everything
*
# But not these files...
!.gitignore
!/projectA/Makefile
!/projectB/Makefile
```

It turns out git can't track the Makefiles in the subdirectories of `projectA` and `projectB`. One solution is to create `.gitignore` file in the subdirectories, but I don't like it because I have to manually create a lot of different `.gitignore` files. Any idea how to do that in the `.gitignore` of git root dir?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

1. *You need to track the folder in order to track the Makefile in the folder*
2. *But we don't want to track anything in the folder*
3. *Except the Makefile*.

Put these pieces together to get these three lines in your .gitignore

> !/projectA/
>   /projectA/*
>   !/projectA/Makefile

It's a bit verbose, but I don't know of a shorter method.

Comment: It seems not working. When I run `git status`, it reports `projectA/` as untracked instead of `projectA/Makefile`

Comment: The reason you only see the folder is that you need to track a folder in order to track anything in that folder.  Do `git add projectA` and you will stage only the Makefile in that folder.

Comment: @RNAer, use `git status --ignored --untracked-files=all` instead.